# Web Part Header Colour Change

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

[image]

Can anyone help? I want to change the whole header colour to green but it just changes the Title strip where the text is. Any ideas?

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartTitleWPQ3 h2
{
   background:#50B848 !important; 
   color:white !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of this particular web part or all web parts on this page.?

Answer (score 1):

Remove H2, and use background-color

```
 #WebPartTitleWPQ3 {  background:#50B848 !important;color:white !important;}
```

Comment: This seems to stop the font from changing colour but it still doesn't colour the whole header.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#WebPartTitleWPQ3
{
   background:#50B848 !important; 
   color:white !important;
}
</style>

Answer (score 1):

We can use the CSS style below to achieve it.

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartWPQ3_ChromeTitle{
    background-color:#50B848 !important;
}
#WebPartWPQ3_ChromeTitle h2{
    color:white !important;
}
#WebPartWPQ3_ChromeTitle a{
    color:white !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of Header text for that particular web part only, then you can use following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
     #WebPartWPQ3_ChromeTitle a{
         color: green !important;
      }
</style>
```

And if you want to change the color of all web parts on the page. Use following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ms-webpart-titleatext a{
         color: green !important;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: have you tried this?